# Regular expression to replace all ../../ with / URLs to be used in visual studio

Tags: regex, visual-studio, relative-path

I've recently inherited a site created in Dreamweaver where all URLs use the 'up one level' notation e.g. "../products/" and I would like to do a global find and replace with root path e.g. "/products/".

What's the regular expression I need to use in the **Visual Studio Find & Replace Dialog** to replace the following matches:

"../../../products" with "/products/"
"../../products/" with "/products/"
"../news" with "/news/"
"../*" with "/*"

All the URLs are relative to the root so I think I just need to replace any number of matched '../' with '/'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the following

```
(\.\./)+
```

with a single `/`

(Backup the project first ;) )

Answer (score 1):

It's probably easiest to first replace `(\.\./)+` with `/`.

Then check if your paths ends in a `/`, and add it if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
(\.\./)+.+
```

Which converts to ../ repeated n times, followed by anything repeated n times